# Warning message Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, concurrency, transactions

In Our Application we are using Hibernate for ORM and getting below warning is message

WARN: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread! Delaying action until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]

Is this Warning message can we ignore it or we need to look into it ?

Regards,
Sakumar

Answer (score 7):

You need to look into it. This can only happen when the transaction is started by one Thread and then rolled-back by some other "clean-up" Thread. It might indicate that you started a transaction but never properly closed it or some background clean-up has decided to rollback a long running transaction. Either way, you should dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same WARN message and issue which was causing transactions to timeout (because processing was taking some time... 10+ min).

Issue was that I had a scheduler which was actually TimerService. And when TimerService runs out on scheduled periods it would envoke @Timeout implemented method which would run service with my business logic. The catch here was that @Timeout annotated methods would start a transaction by itself, which meant that for processing some 1000+ records, only one transaction would be active and would timeout after some time. Even if I started new transaction for each record, the first transaction would simply wait for those to finish and would timeout again.

I fixed it by tweaking a logic inside my @Timeout method to only process smaller batches of data but more frequently.